# HTTP request - Moved permanently?

Tags: http, ssl, command-line, telnet

I am trying to take some theoretical study about HTTP into practice. So I tried to make a HEAD (also tried GET but prefer HEAD since I am interested in the actual object) and it went as follows:

```
~$ telnet youtube.com 80
Trying 216.58.211.110...
Connected to youtube.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
HEAD /watch?v=GJvGf_ifiKw HTTP/1.1
Host: youtube.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://youtube.com/watch?v=GJvGf_ifiKw
Date: Thu, 12 Dec 2019 15:48:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: YouTube Frontend Proxy
X-XSS-Protection: 0
```

As you can see, I am requesting the object locating at /watch?v=GJvGf_ifiKw on the host located at youtube.com and this must sum to youtube.com/watch?v=GJvGf_ifiKw which is the URL of the location header field. What's going on here? Why does it say it has moved to the identical location?

Comment: It looks like the response to HEAD was a redirect to https as mentioned by @Kerolos William https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location

Answer (score 4):

If you looked closely to the output you will find that you've been redirected to `HTTPS` as your initial request was telnet on port 80 which is the default `HTTP` port

and since they are enforcing redirection to `HTTPS`

so the it's redirected to identical location BUT over Secured `HTTP` with is `HTTPS`